# SSIS error while loading data from XML to SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, ssis, load, etl

I am getting the following error while loading data from an XML file into a SQL Server database. The database is on my local machine.

> [XML Source [41]] Error: The "XML Source" failed because truncation occurred, and the truncation row disposition on "XML Source.Outputs[Issue].Columns[Description]" at "XML Source.Outputs[Issue]" specifies failure on truncation. A truncation error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.

Comment: Have you manually checked the values that appear in the XML file? It sounds like the `Description` column is too small to hold a value from the XML - or at least SSIS thinks it is, i.e.: if you alter the table in the database you'll need to update all of the references in the SSIS package to suit.

Answer (score 0):

The Values of column "Description" exceeds the Column size given in the output. Either give appropriate size in the output or go to error handling in OLE DB advanced editor and give "ignore failure" in Truncation error output.